# How to access a JSON webservice in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

What is the common way of accessing a web service and getting response JSON as Clojure maps ?

Do we have to use Java's java.net.URLConnection and Some JSON library like GSON ?

Is http-kit the most used library for this purpose, thats what I get via Google?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http). One of its dependencies is a JSON library called [cheshire](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire).

Here's an example of a basic GET request that parses the body as JSON.

```
(clj-http.client/get "http://example.com/foo.json" {:as :json})
```

Answer (score 1):

For asynchronous HTTP you should look at [http.async.client](https://github.com/neotyk/http.async.client)